# WSC Metadata File Creation and Clean Formatting

Tags: deployment, package, wsc

We are using Force WSC library in Java to create Metadata xml files.

Functionality it is working as expected but the files it generates when serialized to file is not clean formatted (with lots of redundant xml namespace definitions with each tag, with different local names).

Here is the Java code we are using to generate the xml:

```java
public static <T> File writeMetadataFile(File file, XMLizable metadata) {

    file.getParentFile()
            .mkdirs();
    try (FileOutputStream so = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        XmlOutputStream out = new XmlOutputStream(so, true);
        metadata.write(new QName(metadata.getClass()
                .getSimpleName()), out, new TypeMapper());
        out.flush();

        return file;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception while writing to file " + file, e);
    }

}
```

Here is the generated Xml for a CustomObject:

```xml
<CustomObject n1:type="CustomObject"
   xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <n2:fullName xmlns:n2="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">test__c</n2:fullName>
 <n3:deploymentStatus xmlns:n3="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">Deployed</n3:deploymentStatus>
 <n4:description xmlns:n4="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"></n4:description>
 <n5:enableActivities xmlns:n5="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">true</n5:enableActivities>
 <n6:externalSharingModel xmlns:n6="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">Private</n6:externalSharingModel>
 <n7:label xmlns:n7="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">test</n7:label>
 <n8:nameField n1:type="n8:CustomField" xmlns:n8="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <n8:displayFormat n1:nil="true" />
  <n8:label>test Name</n8:label>
  <n8:type>Text</n8:type>
 </n8:nameField>
 <n9:pluralLabel xmlns:n9="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">tests</n9:pluralLabel>
 <n10:sharingModel xmlns:n10="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">Read</n10:sharingModel>
</CustomObject>
```

Question is, do you know how we can configure WSC to generate clean formatted xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what we found out about output formatting after lots of trial and error.

**To remove the redundant namespaces in the output**

We were not specifying the namespace for when we initiate the write. So instead of,

```
    metadata.write(new QName(metadata.getClass()
            .getSimpleName()), out, new TypeMapper());
```

it should be

```
    metadata.write(new QName("http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata", metadata.getClass()
            .getSimpleName(), ""), out, new TypeMapper());
```

This will eliminate the majority of redundant namespaces

**To indent with 4 spaces**

When we init the xml out stream as

```
XmlOutputStream out = new XmlOutputStream(so, true);
```

It initialized with two spaces. If you want 4 spaces, init it as

```
XmlOutputStream out = new XmlOutputStream(so, "    ");
```

**If that doesn't cut it:**

If those two possible options doesn't cut it, then you will have to implement your own or extend `XmlOutputStream` and `MxSerializer` to overwrite part of the code to format the way you want it.

Comment: The first two options didn't work as they are prefixed with namespaces though an empty string is given.